# Symfony2: new instance at each service call instead of using the same

Tags: php, symfony

I created a service but each time I call it, it creates a new instance instead of using the same one.
Here is my services.yml:

```
my.sessiondata:
    class: My\Bundle\Service\SessionData
    calls:
        - [ setServices, [@security.context, @service_container, @session, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager] ]
    scope: container
```

And my service:

```
namespace My\Bundle\Service;

class SessionData
{  
    protected $company;


    public function setServices($securityContext, $serviceContainer, $session, $em)
    {
        var_export($this->company);
        if (!$this->company)
        {
            $this->company = "TEST";
            var_export($this->company);
        }
    }
}
```

I call the service in a controller like this :

```
    $sessionData = $this->container->get('my.sessiondata');
```

The view keeps diplaying NULL'TEST' each time I call the controller.

Any idea why the instance is lost ?

Answer (score 14):

During one request, each time you call

```
$this->container->get('my.sessiondata')
```

you'll get the same instance as long as the scope is set to container (which is default).

**Container doesn't share instances between requests.** This is how PHP works. Each request is independent. While you can share some data (for example in a session) all the objects created during a single request are destroyed once it finishes. Next time you hit the server everything needs to be recreated.

Comment: Tks so much for your accurate answer !

Comment: Well actually instance can be shared between the requests. It depends on the app implementation. Traditional app will definitely not do that, but it could be shared in the application servers like http://appserver.io

Comment: @Aistis again, this is not how PHP works by default. All the solutions trying to keep the application alive between http requests (like https://packagist.org/packages/phpfastcgi/fastcgi-daemon) are highly experimental.

Comment: @JakubZalas sure it is not by default, as I meant by saying *traditional*. However, production-ready solutions for shared request applications already exists and we should not ignore the fact PHP could be used with more advanced (let's say *nontraditional* for PHP!) patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with `scope`s. The `scope` of a service controls how long an instance of a service is used by the container. As the Symfony2 docs shows:

`container` (the default one): The same instance is used each time you request it from this container.
`prototype`: A new instance is created each time you request the service.

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: YourClass
        scope: prototype
```

More about Scopes [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html).

Answer (score 0):

In newer Symfony versions [this behavior can be achieved](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html) by adding the `shared: false` property to your service.

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\SomeNonSharedService:
        shared: false
        # ...
```