# Symfony functional test: Current request not set when fetching service from container

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit, symfony3.x

One of my services depends on the HTTP_HOST value in the currentRequest object from the requestStack. When this service is used in a functional test it works because I create the client with the host parameter:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
   'HTTP_HOST' => 'test.' . $this->domain
));
```

At some point I have the need to get a service from the container that has a dependency on the request so i thought i used the client created with the host value to fetch the service:

```
$client->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('service')->someMethod();
```

But the request object is no longer set when the constructer of this service is is called.

Is there any way I can use this service in the test function with a dependency on the Request object ?

Related code:

ControllerTest.php

```
//Create client with HTTP_HOST
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
   'HTTP_HOST' => 'test.' . $this->domain
));

//Do some request services depending on the request object work because the client is initiated with the HTTP_HOST value
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $redirectUrl);        
$this->assertEquals(
   1,
   $crawler->filter('html:contains("feedback")')->count()
);

//Now I want to check if email feedback is send. This process starts in a EventSubsriber 
//I have to trigger this event myself because the $event variable consist of fake data.
$client->getContainer()->get('event_subscriber')->process($event);

//now collect the mail and do some checks
$mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
$this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());
```

Comment: did you resolve this issue? I have same weird behavior with container and services in my integration tests.

Comment: It looks like you have new services for each request, see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486700/2119164

Comment: @SerhiiPolishchuk I did not resolve this yet. Your comment makes sense but my test works a little different.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the Container directly from your created client, as described in [the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/testing.html#accessing-the-container):

```
$client->getContainer()->get('service')->someMethod();
```

It may still be necessary to mock the whole service but more code examples would be needed..

Comment: That produces the same error, still miss the Request object. sure i could mock all the dependencies but there are a lot and in the end i want to check if some mail is send. I would be easier to let the container handle all the dependencies

Comment: But you have requested something with $client->request('GET', 'whatever') ?

Comment: Well yes but separately, see the related code in my updated answer.

Comment: Profiler is enabled as described here https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/testing/profiling.html?

Comment: Yes I know, I left some lines out because the profiler is not part of the issue

Comment: Only one idea left, mayby there is a redirect in your request, so $client->followRedirects(false); before the request could be an option. If you create a repository on Github, I could have a deeper look into it.

Comment: As of Symfony 4.1 we can use `$container = self::$container;` to get the container in a functional test. https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/testing.html#accessing-the-container .